# No module named 'encodings' en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, centos7

Tengo un servidor con Centos 7 y ps estoy trabajando con python, necesito instalar un modulo con pip3 pero siempre que lo voy a ejecutar me sale el siguiente error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f9a97e87740 (most recent call first):
Aborted
```

ya estuve buscando por todo google y las soluciones no me sirven.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: ¿qué módulo es el que intentas ejecutar? ¿Estás usando entornos virtuales o lo instalas globalmente con `sudo`?

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, el error salia siempre que trataba de instalar cualquier modulo, estaba ejecutando el pip3 install gcc aunque ya lo pude solucionar ejecutando los comandos, unset PYTHONPATH y unset PYTHONHOME por si a alguien le ocurre este mismo error.

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo pude solucionar ejecutando los comandos: unset PYTHONPATH y unset PYTHONHOME por si a alguien le ocurre este mismo error.